# Inserindo CSV no PostgreSQL com NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, csv, sql-insert

Quero inserir um CSV em uma tabela postgresql.
O CSV contém linhas com vários números de colunas.

Ex:

```
     1,2,3
     1,2,3,4,5
     1,2,3,4,5,6
     1,2,3,4
```

Ao realizar a inserção, ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
bind message supplies 7 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 11.
```

Nesse caso meu CSV tem até 11 colunas, mas a inserção da primeira linha só tem 7 colunas.
Podem me ajudar?

Meu código:

```
const query = "INSERT INTO category(activitiesheart,activitiessteps,opa,oxe,umt,erf,mar,zap,asd,ser,ver)
 VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11)";

pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  try {
    csvData.forEach((row) => {
      client.query(query, row, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err.stack);
        } else {
          console.log("inserted " + res.rowCount + " row:", row);
        }
      });
    });
  } finally {
    done();
  }
});
```

Comment: No lugar dos valores faltantes o que deseja fazer? preencher com nulo?

Comment: isto, é uma opção também :)

Comment: se possível, o número de valores do VALUE ser dinâmico...

Comment: Outra coisa é como tem certeza que o elemento na posição "6" pertence à posição 6? Como garante que ele não é o elemento da posição 11 por exemplo?

Comment: O código percorre cada linha do CSV. Na primeira linha por exemplo, ele quer inserir 7 elementos, porém o insert está esperando 11 elementos.

No momento que o CSV tem 11 elementos, a inserção ocorre perfeitamente.
Então ai está o problema, o máximo de elementos são 11, porém existem linhas com menos elementos.

Comment: Se conter 7 elementos, o restante inserido pode ser null, 0, qualquer coisa.

Comment: eu entendi o problema. Eu consigo ver pelo sql a posição 6 do array é `erf` como eu sei que o valor da posição 6 corresponde ao elemento `erf` e não ao elemento `ver`? Existe alguma garantia de ordem nos elementos do array?

Comment: A ordem é 6 = erf, como você disse. Não existe garantia, pois se o valor não existe, insere null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver é fazer um laço para preencher os valores faltantes, se for possível inserir valores nulo em seu banco de dados então é possível fazer uma função para "completar" com nulos os valores do array. Depois de normatizar o tamanho do array é possível fazer a inserção sem problemas.

Segue um exemplo:

```
//...
csvData.forEach((row) => {
    while (row.length < 11) {
        row.push(null)  //ou row.push('')
    }
    client.query(query, row, (err, res) => {
// resto do código ...
```

Seria a mesma ideia caso os valores a serem preenchidos forem valores inteiros.

OBS.: Desta maneira que o código foi implementado estamos assumindo que o dado lido é posicional e que valores faltantes podem ser completados com nulo na ordem em que aparecem e os faltantes são sempre os ultimos elementos (não existe a possibilidade de que valores faltantes sejam os valores intermediários).

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, acredito ter conseguido resolver. Obrigado!!